# Eclipse error The package javax.xml.datatype is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml - split packaging

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, java-platform-module-system

When migrating from Java 8 to Java 11, I am seeing the following warnings in Eclipse[Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)].

```
The package javax.xml.datatype is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
DatatypeConfigurationException cannot be resolved to a type
DatatypeFactory cannot be resolved
```

[Eclipse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUvC3.png)

[Split packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxdqD.png)

I understand that two modules can not have same package. There is not a way to remove `java.xml` module from JRE 11 module path as it removes other dependent packages and causing more errors.

I am using ivy dependency manager. When I add `<exclude org="xml-apis"/>` in ivy.xml, the Eclipse errors go away but it is required at run-time and caused `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I see that others have ran into this and the solution that worked for them is to remove the jar from the classpath but that is not working because of `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Is there a setting that will tell Eclipse to refer to class path for `java.xml` package instead of module path?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Since `java.xml` is part of the system library, it can be excluded (assuming it is not required, which is unlikely in your case), but it cannot be moved to the classpath. You have to get rid of this dependency to be able to migrate your project from Java 8 to 11.